# Azure WebRole - how do I remote debug when there is more than one site hosted as part of a WebRole?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I am deploying more than one website as part of a WebRole deployment in Azure. Example .csdef to illustrate what I mean:

```
<Sites>
  <Site name="MySiteOne" physicalDirectory="../MySiteOne">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="HttpsIn" endpointName="HttpsIn" hostHeader="mysiteone.cloudapp.net" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
<Site name="MySiteTwo" physicalDirectory="../MySiteTwo">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="HttpsIn" endpointName="HttpsIn" hostHeader="mysitetwo.cloudapp.net" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
```

The deployment works fine and I have two sites set up in IIS as I would expect. However, I am unable to remote debug either site. Once they are both activated (i.e. have loaded from the initial request sent following deployment), I go to Remote Debug in Visual Studio. When I try to Attach to Process -> w3wp.exe there are actually 4 of these processes (2 sites x 2 instances) and I cannot select which one to debug. I cannot even do this by Trial & Error as the message that comes up is that there is more than one object to attach to.

Is it possible to remote debug multiple sites in Azure? Or will I need to deploy each site as a seperate WebRole/instance (and pay the cost to do this - thanks Microsoft) in order to do this?